# Return "normal" variable from async Task Method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

In one of my methods, I want to create a car like this:

```
public string[] CreateCar()
{
    string[] wheels = CreateWheels();

    // Also add motor and other stuff here
    string[] motor = ...;

    return new string[][]{ wheels, motor, ... };
}
```

Here four wheels a created and they don't depend on each other.
Hence, I can place them in multiple `tasks`, do be parallelised. (In my real code, this is not possible with a parallel-for loop)

```
public string[] CreateWheels()
{
    Task FL = Task.Run(() => CreateWheel("front left");
    Task FR = Task.Run(() => CreateWheel("front right");
    Task BL = Task.Run(() => CreateWheel("back left");
    Task BR = Task.Run(() => CreateWheel("back right");

    // Here I really want to wait for all wheels to be created!
    // STOP THE PROCESS HERE UNTIL ALL WHEELS ARE COMPLETED!!!
    string[] wheels = await Wask.WhenAll(FL, FR, BL, BR); 

    return wheels;
}
```

And one single wheel is created something like that:

```
public string CreateWheel(string position)
{
    // Here a wheel is created, whatever it takes :)
    return "wheel " + position;
}
```

**My problem now is the following:**
In order to get the code compiled, it forces me to mark `CreateWheels` as an `async`-Method. Otherwise I cannot use `await`.
⇒ But this forces me to change its return-value to be a `Task<string[]>`
⇒ However, then I need to put an `await` in front of `CreateWheels()` in the `CreateCar`-Method in order to get the string array and not the Task itself

⇒ Then the cycle repeats, since now, there is an `await` in the `CreateWheels`, forcing me to make it `async` ... and so on, and so on ...

This cycle repeats all the way up, until it finally comes to a `void` method, where you don't need to extract the return value with an `await`

**What is the way out of this cycle, if I only want to wait for all wheels to be finished at the marked point?**

Comment: Unless `CreateCar` is a particularity demanding method then I don't see why you want to use `Task.Run` to execute it.

Comment: `string[] wheels = Task.WhenAll(FL, FR, BL, BR).Result;` should work

Comment: @UnholySheep: oh thats nice! Do all tasks still get executed in parallel then?

Comment: Yes you've discovered what Stehpen Cleary says is that once you go Async the code tends to have to be totally converted to Async. Not a bad idea in today's world. Node is async first.  It's also not recommended to mix sych and async, but it can be done.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to make the code [async all the way down](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)?

Comment: not in particular, I'm pretty new to asynchronous programming. hence, I din't want to change that much in the rest of the code

Comment: As others have mentioned async tends to be "infectious" in a way. Depending on how deeply nested this code is it can be kind of a pain to swap everything over, but its less of a pain than trying to debug any deadlock conditions you may end up with from using `.Result` on a task IMO.

Comment: ok thanks! maybe then i have to spread the async-disease all over my code :) at the moment, we should be practised in that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] wheels = Wask.WhenAll(FL, FR, BL, BR).Result;
```

would do what you want.  Those individual Tasks will still be run in parallel.

The downside is that your calling thread will block until these tasks are all resolved.

Comment: NIce thanks!
That my calling thread is block cannot be avoided anyways, if the following code depends on the outcome of CreateWheels() right?

Comment: Instead of using `WhenAll().Result` why not use `WaitAll()` since it is the synchronous counterpart to `WhenAll`?

Comment: @TylerHundley Either is ok.  WhenAll will unwrap all the tasks in one go and leave you with a normal array of strings.  If you compare my answer to Marc's then you see that even after calling WaitAll he still has to deal with several Tasks and call Result several times.  But it's just preference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to be synchronous, then `Task.WaitAll` may help, i.e.

```cs
Task.WaitAll(FL, FR, BL, BR);
var wheels = new[] {FL.Result, FR.Result, BL.Result, BR.Result};
```

If you want this to be asynchronous, you'll need to make the method `async [Value]Task<string[]>`, and propagate the async-ness throughout. Async is adhesive - it sticks to everything; but:

```cs
string[] wheels = await Task.WhenAll(FL, FR, BL, BR);
```

However, frankly, I suspect that there's no need for either in this case; parallelism *isn't cheap* - and is probably adding a *lot* more overhead than it is worth here.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve parallelism by starting multiple tasks with `Task.Run`, but why not use a specialized tool for the job like the [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq) library? Not only you'll avoid using the [`Task.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result) property, which is notorious for causing nasty deadlocks when combined with `await`, but you'll also get the ability to define the maximum degree of parallelism as a bonus:

```
var wheelNames = new[] { "front left", "front right", "back left", "back right" };
string[] wheels = wheelNames
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
    .Select(x => CreateWheel(x))
    .ToArray();
```